# field with multiple classes will if statement match

Tags: jquery

if I have a field that has multiple classes:

```
<input type='text' class='req small inside' id='car'>
<input type='text' class='req small inside' id='truck'>
<input type='text' class='small inside' id='boat'>
```

will the if statement below match for the id car and truck?

```
 $.each($('.inside'),function(){
      if ($(this).attr('class') == "req"){
           //do something;
      }
 });
```

if I do `alert($(this).attr('class')`  the result is `req small inside` for car and truck  and  `small inside` for boat

Comment: yep it is, should i do anything with this question?

Comment: No problem, bart2puck, it will get closed as a duplicate by community moderators. You can leave it be :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check it.

```
 $('.inside').each(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('req')){
           //do something;
      }
 });
```

And you could also just do it in selector.

```
// the elements with class 'inside' and 'req' at the same time.
$('.inside.req').each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: I love it when its easy. thanks.

Comment: ... that's the entire point of jQuery, to make it easy :p Be sure to check out that documentation, it really should be your first source. A Google query like "jquery check for class" will get you right to the docs page (`hasClass` is the first result when I do that search)

Comment: i was stuck in a frame of mind and your right should have checked elsewhere.  Got locked into thinking one way, and it must only work that way...thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, we all started out not knowing! Effective research is probably the first thing you learn as you become a more experienced developer in any language. Glad you got an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/). Check whether the class is present or not inside the element or selector

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('req'))
```

Comment: You answer it but forgot to explain it . This one is the most important in SO. Anyway I put for you